# Access denied error on root site path of SharePoint online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, modern-experience, office-365-developer

We have a SharePoint online Modern site where no one has access. Using PowerShell we have broken the unique permission of Home.aspx page and added read permission to all.

Now when user opens the site using URL `https://tesing.sharepoint.com/abc/` they **get access denied** but if they give full path `https://testing.sharepoint.com/abc/SitePages/Home.aspx` they are able to see the content. Home.aspx is default page of the site

Comment: Dou your users have any permission to the site at all, or only the Home.aspx?

Comment: @BennySkogberg only Home.aspx also Home.aspx is default page of the site

Comment: If your users don't have read access to the site, the browser can't find the reference to the default page (Home.aspx). So you need to give them read access to the site itself.

Comment: @BennySkogberg but the requirement is that user wont have access to the site , they will be able to access only landing page where there is SPFx webpart from where they will raise access request.

Comment: In this case I would create an empty subsite only containing Home.aspx and nothing else. Users have read access to the subsite, but since it doesn't contain valuable data, its the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the user has access to the entire SharePoint site collection, not just to the Site Pages Library.

**Here is my test:**

1.Naviagtion to Site Permissions page (/_layouts/15/user.aspx) as a site admin.

2.Click **Check Permissions**. In my test, user named test

[image]

3.Go to the Site Pages library, click **Library settings**

[image]

4.On the Settings page, click "**Permissions for this document library**" link

[image]

5.On the Library Permissions page, click "**Check Permissions**". In my test, user:test has Edit permission in the Site Pages Library

[image]

[image]

[image]